# Will Type.GetType() slow down based on the size and complexity of the object you are retrieving?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have an application that is using basic reflection today to grab classes.

```
Type type = Type.GetType(mynamespace.myclassname);
object o = System.Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

I wanted to see how efficient the reflection was running so I generated about 150,000 objects in this manner to see if performance ever degraded and performance was fast and steady.

However, this got me thinking:  Will the call to Type.GetType() actually slow down depending on the size and complexity of the class being passed into the GetType() method?

For  example: Lets say we wanted to use GetType() to retrieve a complex class made up of 30 private variables, 30 private methods and 30 public methods versus a class that has only one very simple public Add(int, int) method which sums up two numbers.

Would Type.GetType slow down significantly if the class being passed in is a complex class  versus a simple class?

thanks

Comment: `GetType()` or `CreateInstance()`?

Comment: I believe GetType is resolved at compile time and CreateInstance uses meta data so there is no iterating over the class properties as you seem to imply. Can someone confirm this? (BTW I upvoted, not the down vote, as its an interesting question)

Comment: I am sorry for any confusing in my wording above. I am specifically referring to the GetType() method call prior to any instantiation via System.Activator.CreateInstance(). Thank you

Comment: I edited the wording to clear up any confusion in what I am asking now.  thank you. I am specifally referring to the GetTyp() call itself.

Comment: Some references... (John Skeet) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353342/performance-of-object-gettype   MSDN, seems GetType is a reflection call but "Fast and Light Functions" as MS calls them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to my understanding of things, (and I am just a humble experienced programmer, I am not one of the creators of the language,) the complexity of the class which is being referred does not in any way whatsoever affect the performance of `GetType()`.

The complexity of the instantiated class will of course affect the performance of `CreateInstance()`, but that is to be expected: the larger the class is, the more stuff it contains, the more code will need to be executed in order to fully construct it.

Perhaps you are confusing `GetType()` with `CreateInstance()`, because I notice you say "Would Type.GetType slow down significantly when instantiating the complex class versus the simple class?" while in fact `GetType()` does not instantiate anything, `CreateInstance()` does.

Answer (score 5):

An instance of the Type object fitting to your type is created when the type is loaded. This (one-time) process will obviously be more or less expensive depending on the type implementation.

After this, a call to GetType() will give you a reference to this readily-prepared instance, and will thus not degarde over time or complexity.