# Best way to reflect child property to parent

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have some legacy code to be refactored.
At first, I have a child class interface: `IChild`. and some classes that implements that interface, like: `ChildType1 : IChild`, `ChildType2 : IChild` and `ChildType3 : IChild`.

The parent has the child types properties, and each time only one of them get initialized example if `ChildType1` has value then `ChildType2` and `ChildType3` are `null`:

```
class Parent
{
    public ChildType1 Type1 { get; set; }
    public ChildType2 Type2 { get; set; }
    public ChildType3 Type3 { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

The `IChild` holds some important property Enum:

```
public interface IChild
{
    ImportantEnum MyEnum { get; set; } 
    //
}
```

My question: regarding the fact I do not know which one of the Types are initiated, what is the best way to make the child `MyEnum` property to be available through the parent api?

I'm open for refactoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me like you need to change your `Parent` class - and it looks, based on the information you've provided so far, that this is a perfect candidate for the use of generics:

```
class Parent<TChild> where TChild : IChild
{
    public TChild Child { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is the name for this design pattern??

Comment: This is not a design pattern, it's a .Net framework capability as old as .Net 2.0. It's just called Generics. You can read all about it in [official documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)

Answer (score 1):

I would refactor it so that you directly expose the current IChild instance, from which it is trivial to query for MyEnum.

```
class Parent
{
    Public IChild Child { get; set; }
}
...
Parent p = new Parent();
IChild child = p.Child;
Type childType = p.Child.GetType();
ImportantEnum val = child.MyEnum
```

Comment: Is `GetType();` expensive?

Comment: I haven't found it to be expensive when I've used it.

Comment: Here's a question about the efficiency of GetType: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353342/performance-of-object-gettype