# GUI optimize nested foreach

Tags: c#, wpf

Can anyone assist on below WPF GUI how to convert to Linq due to low performance:

```
foreach (Grid b in main_grid.Children)
{
    foreach (Control s in b.Children)
    {
        if (s.GetType() == typeof(Button))
        {
            if (s.Tag.ToString() == message)
            {
                if (status == "OIRS_INUSE")
                {
                    s.Background = Brushes.Orange;
                }
                else
                {
                    s.Background = defaultBackground;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "How to convert to LINQ due to low performance"? Why do you think LINQ would yield better performance? LINQ still has to do a `foreach`.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Linq will not help your perfomance

Comment: `s.GetType() == typeof(Button)` can be just `s is Button`

Comment: I'd like to answer this question. I've more optimizations. Please vote to reopen.

Comment: While I agree LINQ or no LINQ is not the issue here, at least OP has formulated its underlying issue (performance).

Comment: @LohZhiCheng : I'd suggest that you give more details about your performance issues in your question. Some numbers (size of lists, time taken, memory used...) are relevant to such question, along with your objective you would consider as acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are asking the wrong question. Linq doesn't help.

One way to speed up this loop is to reduce the workload of its bottleneck:

```
foreach (Grid b in main_grid.Children)
{
    foreach (Control s in b.Children)
    {
        if (s.SomeEnumValue == SomeEnum.Value)
        {
            s.Background = Brushes.Orange;
        }
        else
        {
            s.Background = defaultBackground;
        }
    }
}
```

First comparison `if (s.GetType() == typeof(Button))` [is costly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353342/performance-of-object-gettype):

```
for 100 million calls:

typeof(Test): 2756ms
TestType (field): 1175ms
test.GetType(): 3734ms
```

you'll have more than 5 times slower than a simple field comparison.

Second comparison `if (s.Tag.ToString() == message)` and third comparison `status == "OIRS_INUSE"` [are costly](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-compare-strings)

Moreover, the second comparison contains a ToString method which has its own cost.

So get rid of all these expensive comparisons and replace them with a simple field comparison such as an enum which is cheap.

Comment: Does `Control` have a property called `SomeEnumValue`?

Comment: Could LINQ's `OfType` be of use?

Comment: Why do you think `var` avoids a cast? Or that casting is expensive?

Comment: @DStanley thanks to your comment I found out `foreach (ExplicitType item in collection)` isn't expensive at all. I removed the last part of my answer.

Comment: @mjwills I'm suggesting OP to use a better comparison rather than parse and compare strings, so `SomeEnumValue` could be anything such as Tag or a custom property. I also removed the part about avoiding casting (look at my comment above) so `OfType` could be used but it wouldn't speed it up because it would still be applied to each element separately, just like inside of a loop

Comment: @mjwills I just tested a quick sample with `OfType` and I found out it's about twice as slow as `(s.GetType() == typeof(type))` I don't know why!